# how can I filter base on two columns in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, filter, sqlalchemy

I have a flask app, and a table with two columns, one for date and one for hour.
I have a appointment form and I want to check if the date+time has already taken.
My module looks like this:

---

form = DateForm()

```
if form.validate_on_submit():

    if Appointment.query.filter_by(date=form.date.data).filter_by(hour=form.hour.data):
```

But looks like the only filter that accept is date because raise my flash message even if the time if free. i.e., it rejects me because of the date
Any suggestions on how can filter also the time column?
My goal is to reject if for example in my table exists 10/12/2021 10:00 but accept if the 11:00 is available.
I hope I have been clear in what I want to achieve
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't forget to actually grab the objects with something like `.first()`, `.all()`, etc...

Comment: `Appointment.query.filter_by(date=form.date.data,hour=form.hour.data)` you can set multiple filter using filter_by, or use .filter and `and_` expression.

Comment: I've already tested that and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could solve it!
Apparently, it was a format-type problem. I add to the form.hour.data like this:
form.hour.data.strftime('%H:%M')

Also I change a little the code like so:

---

if Appointment.query.filter(
and_(
Appointment.date.like(form.date.data),
Appointment.hour.like(form.hour.data.strftime('%H:%M'))
)
).first():

With that simple modification, the validation started to work as I expected.